# How to add new voices to Android Pico TTS?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to add new voices (e.g. a female voice or a cartoon voice) to the existing Pico TTS engine that ships with Android. It ships with only one male voice. I know there are other TTS engines that support multiple voices but they are not free. I want my Android application to be able to use multiple voices.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The creator of the Pico TTS engine is SVOX, and they are not likely to make it easy for their free offering to compete with their “[Classic Text-To-Speech Engine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.svox.classic)”.