# How to change the voice of a TTS engine

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I want to use my own voice as a TTS voice on android, can that be done in anyway?

I am using android studio v0.1 and compiling against 4.2 jellybean, have tried pitch and speed rate but nothing works..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729283/how-do-you-create-your-own-text-to-speech-voice

Comment: Yes, that can be done. But you will have to develop/make your own TTS engine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you are using pico tts for your synthesis. Unfortunately you are not able to create your own voice database.

[Previous question about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924788/how-to-add-new-voices-to-android-pico-tts)

Maybe you can try to change your text-to-speech engine. These are the most famous on android devices:

http://www.geoffsimons.com/2012/06/7-best-android-text-to-speech-engines.html